# Marketing Cloud- How to test bcc/cc are working or not?

Tags: marketing-cloud

The CC/BCC fields are updated in Triggered Sends. Now, I want to validate/test if the emails are getting CC/bcc’ed or not.

Need someone who is familiar with testing scenarios in Triggered Sends/Marketing Cloud.

Comment: What is the issue you are having? Are you receiving any errors? To test the TSD, all you need to do is send an email through it and verify if the email is received in those inboxes. Make sure you pause, publish changes and restart your TSD to ensure you get the most up to date version.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing from Comments to answer for easier reference:

To test the Trigger Send Definition (TSD), all you need to do is send an email through it and verify if the email is received in those inboxes. Make sure you pause, publish changes and restart your TSD to ensure you get the most up to date version.